# Тире или запятая и тире перед вводным словом

Tags: вводные-слова

Почему перед вводным словом ставятся разные знаки в предложении с однородными членами и в сложном предложении?

Примеры:

**Однородный ряд:**   С лица и с поступков его исчезло само собою сомнение, нерешительность — словом, все колеблющиеся и неопределённые черты.

**Сложное предложение (БСП):** Мужчины пили, спорили и хохотали, – словом, ужин был чрезвычайно весел.  Также другие примеры: Собака исчезла, – наверное, ее кто-то украл. Ведущий не смог подтвердить никаких фактов, – очевидно, это все же только слухи.

Тире нужно в обоих случаях, оно обозначает паузу перед обобщением. К структуре БСП относится только тире, а две запятые будто бы обособляют вводное слово. Но куда тогда девается запятая в предложении с однородными членами, поглощается тире? Или в сложном предложении мы имеем единый знак - запятую или тире, чтобы отличать сложное предложение от простого?

Answer (score 2):

Розенталь Д. Э. Параграф 99.
Если вводное слово стоит после перечисления однородных членов и предшествует обобщающему слову, то перед вводным словом ставится только тире (без запятой), а после него – запятая, например: Книги, брошюры, журналы, газеты – словом, все виды печатной продукции валялись на его письменном столе в полном беспорядке (см. §89, п. 2). Но: Мужчины пили, спорили и хохотали, – словом, ужин был чрезвычайно весел (Пушкин); На одном из перегонов разговорились про частные дела, кто откуда, чем занимался, в какой среде вырос, – словом, на темы бескрайные (Фурманов) (оба предложения сложные, и запятая перед тире ставится на основании общего правила разделения частей сложного предложения).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне как раз не очень понятно объяснение Розенталя. В БСП в приведенных примерах (при отсутствии обобщающего слова) ставилось бы тире, а не запятая, так почему же мы ставим там два знака (запятую и тире)?  А если переставить вводное слово, то получится: Собака исчезла  –  ее, наверное, кто-то украл. Здесь не нужна запятая?

Comment: Тире в приведенных примерах  относится к структуре БСП: вторая часть обозначает вывод, отнесенный к первой части.  (С чего бы это нам вводное слово обособлять с помощью тире). Если убрать вводное слово, то тире в БСП будет писаться  на тех же основаниях.

Comment: В БСП, который Вы приводили в качестве примера, тире ставится между частями сложного предложения, а запятая перед вводным словом, поэтому нужно два знака. В ПП тире ставится перед обобщающим словом.